# how to use cvFilter2D function with a 1-dimension-kernel

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 4 kernels that are A,At,B and Bt separately.

1. A   [1 0 0 -1]
2. At(A's transpose matrix)   1   0   0 -1
3. B   [0.50 0 0 -1 0 0 0.50]
4. Bt(B's transpose matrix)
     0.50   0   0   -1   0   0
     0.50

I run the function `cvFilter2D` with the 4 kernels separately. Following are the partial results with different kernels:

1. A
     0.003921568   -0.007843137
   0.000653625 -0.009803951
   -0.003921628    -0.009803891
   -0.007843137    -0.007843137
   -0.009803951    -0.003485799
2. At
   -0.019082069    0.002332032
   -0.008974016    0.000923872
   -0.000217795    -0.00043577
   0.002332032 -0.000512481
   0.000923872 -0.000540674
   -0.00043577 -0.000217855
3. B
   -2.68E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.68E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.68E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.67E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.67E-25   -2.67E-25
4. Bt
   -2.65E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.66E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.67E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.67E-25   -2.67E-25
   -2.67E-25   -2.67E-25

From the results,the function calculate the wrong results with kernel B and Bt. Who can tell me how to run the cvFilter2D correctly with the 4 kernels?

Answer (score 0):

I found a function in internet as following.It's said that The function is similar with "conv2" in matlab. Any advice to improved the function will be appreciated!

```
enum ConvolutionType {
    /* Return the full convolution, including border */  
    CONVOLUTION_FULL,  
    /* Return only the part that corresponds to the original image */  
    CONVOLUTION_SAME,   
    /* Return only the submatrix containing elements that were not influenced
    by the border */ 
    CONVOLUTION_VALID 
}; 
void conv2(const Mat &img, const Mat& kernel, ConvolutionType type, Mat& dest) 
{   
    Mat source = img;   
    if(CONVOLUTION_FULL == type)
    {     
        source = Mat();
        const int additionalRows = kernel.rows-1, additionalCols = kernel.cols-1;     
        copyMakeBorder(img,source,(additionalRows+1)/2,additionalRows/2,\
        additionalCols+1)/2,additionalCols/2,BORDER_CONSTANT,Scalar(0)); 
    }     
    Point anchor(kernel.cols - kernel.cols/2 - 1, kernel.rows - kernel.rows/2 - 1);   
    int borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT;
    Mat kernelInvert;
    flip(kernel,kernelInvert,0);
    filter2D(source,dest,img.depth(),kernelInvert,anchor,0,borderMode);
    if(CONVOLUTION_VALID == type) 
    {
        dest = dest.colRange((kernel.cols-1)/2, dest.cols - kernel.cols/2)\                
                .rowRange((kernel.rows-1)/2, dest.rows - kernel.rows/2);
    } 
}
```